# Element locator with prefix 'xpath("//android.widget.edittext[@resourse-id' is not supported

Tags: robotframework, python-appium

I want to input username.
I have tried to find element as below using UIatomator but it throwing error.

```
 Input Text     xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resourse-id='name']")    test
```

I have attached screenshot for reference please help..[please suggest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX0UM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax for xpath. The syntax is:

```
Input Text    xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='name']
```

The format is described in the [Selenium2Library documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html), under the section "Locating or Specifying Elements"

Comment: This are the output after correcting syntax Starting test: Test.TC1
20170512 21:38:26.196 :  INFO : Typing text 'test' into text field 'xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='name']'
20170512 21:38:28.864 :  INFO : </td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><a href="appium-screenshot-1.png"><img src="appium-screenshot-1.png" width="800px"></a>
20170512 21:38:28.866 :  FAIL : ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='name']' did not match any elements.
Ending test:   Test.TC1

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
xpath = "//*[@resource-id='name']/android.widget.EditText"
```

I believe it solves your problem.